# Password manager that keeps vault on local drive

Tags: password-manager

Im looking for an alternative to 1Password as a password manager.

There are quite a few other big names (Last Pass, Dashlane) out there but they all seem to store the passwords in their own cloud. Im looking for a password manager that will allow me to keep the vault on my local drive.

Any recommendations ?

Im running Mac OSX

Answer (score 10):

I have been using [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) for years. It is completely free, with a large community of developers creating plugins for every imaginable use and translating KeePass into many languages.

You can keep the database on your local drive or use a plugin for the cloud solution of your choice, such as Google Drive or MS OneDrive. If you are using a cloud solution, you can sync KeePass to your smartphone.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I've also been looking to make a change.

Comment: I'll second that. I came here to recommend Keepass. I don't think you can beat it. I also synch to Android via DropBox.

Comment: Do they have a official release for OSX ? I can see there are ports but wondered if there is anything offiical

Comment: For mac that should be KeePassX

Comment: @Sam Yes, KeePassX is on the download page for the site I linked. Apologies I did not provide a link directly to KeePassX.

Comment: As an alternative to externally hosted cloud syncing solutions, [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) can also provide cross-platform/computer file syncing and pairs well with KeePass.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your OS distribution you may already have one. Windows, macOS, GNOME and KDE all have built in systems for local credential management.

GNOME has the Keyring for example, and macOS has the Keychain.

Answer (score 0):

one that I personally use in my company is called Passbolt. Open source and self-hostable with double encryption it is safest one on the market, however, it would require you to have a server running (you could do it with XAMP on Windows, and natively with Apache on Linux (probably mac).

Answer (score 0):

Bitwarden!

I host it on my RPi using this rewritten backend: https://github.com/jcs/rubywarden

Supports all platforms!

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, why not be using Keychain, it's built-in in macOS, you don't have to use iCloud but you can as well to share with your iPhone. I've used Keychain on my Mac OSes for quite some time; 3 or 4 years.